# how to fix "Not targeting the latest version of Andriod" error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I was trying to update the targetSdkVersion to 33 and also the "compileSdkVersion to 33, but I had a deprecated line through the "compileSdkVersion" entry, so I changed the code to "compileSdk 33, and now I'm getting and warning code when I run my app on the simulator. Can someone please tell me how to get of this warning. This is the warning line I see:
"Not targeting the latest versions of Android; compatibility modes apply. Consider testing and updating this version. Consult the android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES javadoc for details."

Here is a copy of the code:

```
android {
compileSdk 33
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wastefreemail.wfmconnect"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 17
    versionName "1.3.4"
    testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
namespace 'com.wastefreemail.wfmconnect'
```

}

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
```

}

Comment: "I only see one error line that states the following" - are you sure that is an error, and not a warning? If you look in the "Build" tab do you see any build errors?

Comment: So the app runs fine, but you want to get rid of the warning from the gradle file? You could change `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdk` to 34 if you have a new enough version of Android Studio, or you could just ignore the warning.

Comment: Hi Tyler V, changing things to 34 removed the error...Thank you. One other question, I received the notice from Google, "To ensure that your app is available to new users, update your app to target Android 12 (API level 31).", moving the two Sdk's to 34 would this be a problem? Sorry if it's a crazy question, but I'm new at this.

Comment: No, anything 31 or newer would be fine to address that message, but they are requiring 33 or newer as of August. The current "latest" release is api 33 (34 is an upcoming release) so setting it to 33 would also be fine. You could also ignore that warning for now when you have it at 33. It's not an error - it's just a warning in Android Studio. Have a look [here](https://apilevels.com/) for the current levels.